# Concise mathematical definition of the fusion product on the Verlinde ring?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, loop-groups

The Verlinde ring of a (let us say) simply connected simple compact Lie group has as underlying additive group the Grothendieck group of representations of the central extension $\widehat{LG}$ of the loop of $G$ with the 'positive energy' condition. I'm trying to find a concise mathematical definition of the product on this ring, the so-called *fusion product*. In Freed-Hopkins-Teleman's *Loop groups and twisted K-theory III* they define an $R(G)$-module structure on this additive group using induction of representations (hence a functorial description).

All references I'm reading just mention 'fusion rules', and cite Verlinde, whose 1988 paper is in the journal Nuclear Physics B. Surely we have a more recent discussion along the lines of the FHT construction mentioned above, and not in terms of linear combinations of coefficients of some irreps considered as generators...?

Comment: (A reference for myself: _Confusion and Connes Fusions_, https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/string/archives/000718.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fusion product arises from the braided monoidal structure on the modular tensor category of [adjectives] loop group representations at level $k$ itself. This is the value $Z(S^1)$ of Chern-Simons theory with gauge group $G$ and level $k$ on the circle, and accordingly its braided monoidal structure comes from thinking about what Chern-Simons assigns to a pair of pants / a sphere punctured at three points / a disk with two disks inside it, namely a "bilinear functor"

$$\boxtimes : Z(S^1) \times Z(S^1) \to Z(S^1)$$

which, in terms of the "basis" of $Z(S^1)$ given by the irreducible representations at level $k$, is completely specified by giving a vector space for each triple $(V_i, V_j, V_k)$ of irreducible representations, namely $\text{Hom}(V_i \boxtimes V_j, V_k)$. The dimensions of these vector spaces give the "fusion rules" in the Verlinde ring, and can be thought of as being obtained by inserting the representations $V_i, V_j, V_k^{\ast}$ at the three punctures of a sphere punctured at three points (or something like that).

There are as many ways to describe $\boxtimes$ as there are ways to describe what Chern-Simons assigns to surfaces with boundary: geometric quantization, quantum groups, conformal nets...

If you just want to pass directly to the Verlinde ring then dimensionally reduce everything I said on $S^1$, by which I mean consider $Z(S^1 \times S^1)$ and $S^1$ times a pair of pants, etc.

Comment: "...along the lines of the FHT construction mentioned above" is perhaps the part of my question I should have emphasised much more strongly :-)

Comment: @David: isn't this given in *Loop groups and twisted K-theory I*?

Comment: Not that I can see - they write "Using the Pontryagin product, we are able to define a fusion product on Rτ(LG) for any G at any primitive level τ. We do not, however, give a construction of this product in terms of representation theory."

Comment: @David: if it's not in one of the FHT papers then I think it's an open question to give a description you'd be happy with. (Incidentally, I think the title of this question is misleading; your specifications certainly seem more specific than just "concise mathematical definition.")

Comment: Well, I would be happy to a pointer to any paper that gives detailed definition. I'm just surprised there isn't one like I imagined.

Comment: @David: I'm not familiar with the literature on Chern-Simons, but I'm sure you can get a description of the fusion product in papers on loop group conformal nets, for example.

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer, even though it's not precisely what I wanted - the last comment of Qiaochu is probably the best I'm going to get as far as pointers.

Answer (score 6):

For any triple $(M_0,M_1,M_\infty)$ of positive energy representations of $\widehat{LG}$ at a fixed level, restriction to small punctured discs produces a canonical (up to some scaling which doesn't matter here) action of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_X = \Gamma(X, \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathscr{O}_X)$, where $X$ is the thrice punctured line $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$.  The multiplicity of $M_\infty^\vee$ in $M_0 \boxtimes M_1$ (i.e., the fusion rule) is given by the dimension of the space of coinvariants.  Since you are only asking about dimension, you get the same answer from the dual space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}_X}(M_0 \otimes M_1 \otimes M_\infty, \mathbb{C})$ of conformal blocks.  Looijenga has a [brief treatment of the theory](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~looij101/wzw.pdf).

Comment: "Since you are only asking about dimension" <- do you mean this in the abstract 'you', or me in particular? I'm not asking about dimension, if I inadvertently gave that impression.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Fusion rules are defined as dimensions of certain vector spaces, so any procedure that produces that number gives you a definition of fusion rule.  Could you say a bit more about what sort of answer you are seeking?

Comment: I'm not interested in computations in the Verlinde ring, rather a conceptual--possibly even functorial--description of the fusion product on positive energy representations (in hindsight, this is a better way to say what I would like).